# In what SE would a question with a scifi element about a manga or anime go

Tags: discussion, support, meta

So I am asking in what SE would a question(with a scifi element like a mecha etc) about a manga or anime go? The anime and manga SE or the Scifi and fantasy SE? I ask this because in the scifi and fantasy SE, there are tags, such as [manga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) and [anime](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime), that are actively used.

An example question would be something like this- which doesn't appear to be a scifi question.

[Is Dragonball's hero Son Goku unbeatable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38709/is-dragonballs-hero-son-goku-unbeatable)

OR- this which could be seen as a scifi question:

[How do souls get around?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19231/how-do-souls-get-around)

Both were in the Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, but were about mangas and animes.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Dragon Ball and Bleach may not be "scifi", but they definitely _are_ fantasy.

Comment: See also: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4735/can-you-ask-the-same-question-on-different-ses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of the two examples you posted, the second (about Bleach) was posted before this site existed, so Scifi was the correct place to post it. The first was posted after we entered public beta though.

In my opinion, either of those questions would have worked on either site. They're within our scope here. They're also at least somewhat in scope on Scifi (as neither has been closed). So you're allowed to ask on either site. There's [a meta post on Scifi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/how-do-we-handle-conflicts-with-the-anime-and-movies-sites) regarding this, but the short version is that you're allowed to ask on whichever site you feel is likely to give the best answer. Cross-posting the same question to multiple sites is not allowed though. The same is true for overlap between this site and [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com), [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), and any other network sites we may happen to share some of our scope with (now or in the future).

So, if you think your question is best answered by science fiction fans, [ask on Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). If you think your question is best answered by anime fans, [ask here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

---

With that said, I suspect that for *most* questions about anime/manga, especially for less popular series than Bleach or Dragon Ball, this site is going to be the best option. Scifi has a few knowledgeable users about popular anime series, but here nearly every experienced user will have seen these shows. In fact, in my opinion, the big reason for creating this site in the first place was that there's a lot of anime/manga questions which require specific expertise not common among the larger communities already present on SE. The questions were mostly technically already on topic somewhere on SE, but the expertise was very fragmented. By gathering them in one place, we've created a community which is more specialized on these topics, and hence typically more knowledgeable.

To make this comparison explicit, Scifi seems to have [about 100 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime+or+bleach+or+dragonball+or+dragonball-z+or+manga+or+naruto+or+one-piece) that I could find easily on anime/manga, while we have [nearly 3000](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: But while this site is primarily for anime and manga and people will know about the anime and manga, will they know about the scifi element or will it be better to go to scifi and fantsy SE. That is the question.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock I think it depends on what sort of "scifi element" we're talking about. If you want to understand something which is explainable purely in-universe, I think we'll typically do fine regardless of whether the genre is scifi or anything else. If you want to know how realistic the science is in a particular series, that would usually be off-topic here, but might be allowed on scifi.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and I think I will follow the advice but it still seems like a grey area sorry.

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock It's very much a grey area. Both sites are acceptable, and there's no great way to tell which one will give you the better answer for a particular question. If you post a question on one site and it goes unanswered for a while, moderators will typically honor requests to migrate the post to a different site if you think it you'd get a better response.